# How to find the maximum of a column in Hive?

Tags: hive, max

My code:

```
add jar /home/edureka/Downloads/csv-serde-1.1.2.jar;

Create table loan(id int,loan_amt int,grade string)
row format serde 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
stored as textfile;

load data local inpath 'Desktop/LMS/Hive_Project/Loan Data.csv' into table loan;

select id,loan_amt,grade from loan
where grade="A"
sort by loan_amt desc
limit 5;
```

But my results is wrong.
I am getting some random valuw which is not the top 5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395324/max-in-value-of-columns-in-a-single-row-in-hive

Comment: I am getting result as 9975 is max number but max number should be 37500

Comment: when I change code to:

Comment: select id,loan_amt,grade from loan
where loan_amt>9975
sort by loan_amt desc
limit 5; then I am getting correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select    id,loan_amt as ,grade 
from      loan
where     grade="A"
order by  cast (loan_amt as int) desc
limit     5;
```

#### 1.

`ORDER BY` (and not `SORT BY`)

> **Difference between Sort By and Order By**
>   Hive supports SORT BY which sorts the data per reducer.
>   The difference between "order by" and "sort by" is that the former guarantees total order in the output
>   while the latter only guarantees ordering of the rows within a reducer.
>   If there are more than one reducer, "sort by" may give partially ordered final results.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy

#### 2.

cast `loan_amt` to `int`

> **Limitation**
>   This SerDe treats all columns to be of type String.
>   Even if you create a table with non-string column types using this SerDe, the DESCRIBE TABLE output would show string column type.
>   . The type information is retrieved from the SerDe.
>   To convert columns to the desired type in a table, you can create a view over the table that does the CAST to the desired type.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde

Comment: got same results