# Hive : Get latest n values from columns

Tags: hive, aggregate-functions, hiveql

I want to select the largest n values in hive

```
use mydb;

select greatest_n(10, mycol1, mycol2) from mytab;
```

i am using hive 2.X. in hive 0.13, i was able to run the above and it worked. but now i get

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function greatest_n
```

is there a way to do this in hive 2.X ?

Answer (score 0):

Hive has [**`greatest`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-MathematicalFunctions) function since [Hive-1.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9402).

***Example:***

```
hive> select greatest(1,2,3,4);
4
```

If you don't have **`greatest()`** function then try with the approach mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395324/max-in-value-of-columns-in-a-single-row-in-hive) link.