# I want to find highest row from multiple columns in hive

Tags: sql

```
a b c
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 1
```

here 3 columns are there and i have to find the highest row among these

result would be - 4 4 4

Comment: Take a quick read of a markdown tutorial for help in formatting your posts on SO.. by not formatting your data as code it changed the meaning of it completely (because it was all on one line rather than a  grid )

Comment: okay thankyou actually i am posting my query first time. will do what you said. @CaiusJard

Comment: Please explain why (4,4,4) is higher than (5,5,1)

Comment: Here's a specific example of the ambiguity of your question; Are you saying that `4+4+4` is higher than `5+5+1`?  Or maybe that `4*4*4` is higher than `5*5*1`?  Or maybe you want *(as per one answer below)* the row with the least-worst single value?  We need to know how you propose to score each row.  A comment says this was an interview question; you did start by asking them what they Mean, actually investigate the Requirement?

Comment: @MatBaille . . . Gosh, I was thinking the row with the highest *minimum* value among the columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It always makes me laugh that "no-one" can spell my name correctly, even when it's on the screen ;)  No a personal criticism, just my take on my observation of human psychology...

Comment: @MatBailie even more confusing that typing at-M offers an autocomplete!

Comment: @MatBailie please find the below ans

Comment: @CaiusJard please find the below ans

Comment: @CaiusJard - Not on my android chrome browser.  I mostly answer SO from my phone...

Comment: @MatBailie no way.. I thought I was the only one left crazy enough to put up with autocorrect screwing every `SELECT * FROM t WHERE I'd = 123` SQL I wrote

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've passed this round the think tank here and we find it a good puzzle trying to work out what it means. Another proposal is that 551 is the same as 155 so 444 is higher than 155.

We can turn 3,1,2 into 123 with "least number, and middle number, and greatest number". Middle number is given by the sum of all numbers minus the greatest minus the least

In this case:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY 
  LEAST(a,b,c) DESC,
  a+b+c-GREATEST(a,b,c)-LEAST(a,b,c) DESC,
  GREATEST(a,b,c) DESC 
  LIMIT 1
```

If your hive doesn't have greatest and least then you'll have to [fake it with case when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395324/max-in-value-of-columns-in-a-single-row-in-hive) (I recommend you use a subquery)

Comment: 'Highest row' == least worst row, I like it.  *(Maybe the interview question was designed to test the applicant's ability to identify and investigate ambiguity.  Instead they appear to have replicated the ambiguity here.)*

Comment: this ans was somehow similar but here question is different .. /* select a,b,c,(a+b+c)/3 from table where (a+b+c)/3 >= (select (avg(a)+avg(b)+avg(c))/3 from table) and a>=(select cast(avg(a) as int) from table) and b>=(select cast(avg(b) as int) from table) and c>=(select cast(avg(c) as int) from table); */

Answer (score 0):

If "highest row" means the greatest sum, then it would be

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY a+b+c DESC LIMIT 1
```

if I understood you correctly? Not sure what you want to do about duplicates? What if there is a row 3 4 5?

Comment: No actually sum is the something which can not balance all the column with individual highest number. I also thought about this but unfortunately its not that what question is all about.  I was asked this quest on an interview with different dataset and there they want highest row not the sum of highest row.

Comment: You need to more accurately define what "highest row" means then, because I have no idea what you're saying right now. Why is 444 higher than 551?

Comment: I have asked from recruiter but only short brief was explained with an example of grocery weight items. I will call them again hope will get the better clarification.

Comment: Do you understand the query I wrote?

Comment: it is like row 5 5 1 .. 5(1st highest) 5(1st highest) 1(lowest) thats why we can not consider it.. but in 4 4 4 ... 4(2nd highest) 4(2nd highest) 4(2nd highest) so we can consider it as highest row...   as if we take 5 5 2 & 4 4 4 then also 4 4 4 is highest row as (2) is the 4th highest and 4 is the 2nd highest .... @caius jard

Comment: Yeah, that still doesn't really make any sense. All you did there was tell me that 5 is greater than 4; a fact that, perhaps unsurprisingly, i already know

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    a,b,c,(a+b+c)/3
from
    table
where
    (a+b+c)/3 >= (select (avg(a)+avg(b)+avg(c))/3 from table)
and         a >= (select cast(avg(a) as int) from table)
and         b >= (select cast(avg(b) as int) from table)
and         c >= (select cast(avg(c) as int) from table)
```

Comment: There's no point in the `/3` on ***both*** sides of the `>=`.  Also, if `a >= avg(a)` and so on for b and c, then you already know that `a+b+c >= avg(a+b+c)`.  This appears to have a lot of arithmetic redundency.  Also, it's not guaranteed to return just one row; just with `{1,1,1} , {2,2,2} , {3,3,3} , {4,4,4}` it returns two rows.  You ***still*** haven't defined what you're ***trying*** to accomplish.  The best practice would be to create a test data set that explores different edge cases you can think of, define the expected results for those inputs, then us that as first draft of a *TEST*